# pytest: How to test project-dependent directory creation?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm developing a project that has the following architecture:

```
|-- weather
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- weather.py
|-- library
|   |-- data.json
|-- test
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- test_weather.py
```

I would like to test that performing a save creates the `library` directory if it does not already exist. `test_weather.py` contains:

```
import os
import shutil

from weather import weather

def test_library_creation():
    # Initialize.
    app = weather.WeatherApp()
    temp_data = app.get_data()
    # Library should not exist initially.
    assert not os.path.isdir('library')
    app.save(temp_data)
    # Library should exist after save.
    assert os.path.isdir('library')
    assert os.path.isfile(os.path.join('library', 'data.json'))
    # Cleanup.
    shutil.rmtree('library')
```

However, I may have some data saved in `data.json` that I don't want to delete as a result of running this test.

Does `pytest` have a solution for this case?

---

### EDIT :

`weather.py` contains:

```
import os
import json

DEFAULT_SAVE_PATH = os.path.join('library', 'data.json')

class WeatherApp:
    def get_data(self):
        return dict(temperature=25, humidity=0.5)

    def save(self, data, save_path=DEFAULT_SAVE_PATH):
        with open('data.json', 'w') as jf:
            json.dump(data, jf)
        os.renames('data.json', save_path)
```

Comment: backup your data.

Comment: Use a [temp directory](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/tmpdir.html) instead of testing on real data.

Comment: @hoefling And what would that look like in the form of an answer?

Comment: It depends on your `app.save()` code as you have to mock out the part saving to `cwd/library` to `tmp/library`. Can you provide a [mcve] for that?

Comment: @hoefling Please see my edit to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have already thought about providing a custom save path, you don't even need to mock anything if you don't want to; just pass the custom path derived from the `tmp_path` fixture:

```
def test_library_creation(tmp_path):
    app = weather.WeatherApp()
    temp_data = app.get_data()
    lib_dir = tmp_path / 'library'
    # this check is somewhat redundant because pytest will ensure
    # the temp dir is created from scratch and is empty
    assert not lib_dir.is_dir()
    app.save(temp_data, save_path=str(lib_dir / 'data.json'))
    # Library should exist after save.
    assert lib_dir.is_dir()
    assert (lib_dir / 'data.json').is_file()
    shutil.rmtree(str(lib_dir))
```

Some notes:

1. The string conversion of path-like objects is required only on Python versions older than 3.6; if you use 3.6 or 3.7, you can work directly with path-like objects, e.g.

   ```
   app.save(temp_data, save_path=lib_dir / 'data.json')
   ```

   or

   ```
   shutil.rmtree(lib_dir)
   ```
2. Beware that `os.rename`/`os.renames` are not error-prone against changing filesystems, e.g. you write `data.json` on a local ext4 partition and `save_path` points to a CIFS share, and here comes the error.
3. Maybe the renaming operation is redundant? You can write the data directly to `save_path`. You just need to ensure the target dir exists first, e.g. with `os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(save_path), exist_ok=True)`.
4. If an assertion fails in the test, the line `shutil.rmtree(str(lib_dir))` won't be executed; this is no big deal since the `tmp_path` is created on tmpfs and will be removed after the next reboot anyway. However, if you want to handle the deletion yourself, I would do this in the test teardown using a custom fixture:

   ```
   import os
   import shutil
   import pytest

   from weather import weather


   @pytest.fixture
   def lib_dir(tmp_path):
       d = tmp_path / 'library'
       yield d
       shutil.rmtree(str(d))


   def test_library_creation(lib_dir):
       app = weather.WeatherApp()
       temp_data = app.get_data()
       assert not lib_dir.is_dir()
       app.save(temp_data, save_path=str(lib_dir))
       # Library should exist after save.
       assert lib_dir.is_dir()
       assert (lib_dir / 'data.json').is_file()
   ```

   Now the `lib_dir` will be removed regardless whether the test passes or not.
5. If you want to test the default arguments (the `app.save(temp_data)` case), you will need to monkeypatch the `DEFAULT_SAVE_PATH` constant in the `weather` module. It's pretty easy using the [`monkeypatch`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/monkeypatch.html) fixture:

   ```
   def test_library_creation(monkeypatch, lib_dir):
       app = weather.WeatherApp()
       temp_data = app.get_data()
       assert not lib_dir.is_dir()
       with monkeypatch.context() as m:
           m.setattr(weather, 'DEFAULT_SAVE_PATH', os.path.join(lib_dir, 'data.json'))
           app.save(temp_data)
       # Library should exist after save.
       assert lib_dir.is_dir()
       assert (lib_dir / 'data.json').is_file()
   ```

Comment: Any reason to use `tmp_path` over `tmpdir`?

Comment: Right now, there isn't as both offer more or less identical functionality. However, beware that `tmpdir`/`tmpdir_factory` return `py.path` instances whereas `py` is not developed anymore and `pytest` slowly ditches it from its dependencies. Sooner or later, `tmpdir` will be deprecated and removed from the library. `tmp_path`/`tmp_path_factory` are rewrites that are based on stdlib's `pathlib` and intend to replace `tmpdir`/`tmpdir_factory`.